# Android background color different from expected

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, background

I am testing a simple App, and I have my app theme set to:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
```

So I expected my background color to be 100% black.

In the Android Studio render of the UI, the background is 100% black, but when I lunch the app in some AVD (tested in 4.4.2 AVD and 4.0.3 real tablet), the background turns to be a gradient:

[image]

it's clear it's not black, since there is a black test `ImageButton` that contrasts with the gradient.

Can anyone please explain me why the Android Studio render is now showing the gradient, and why is it there a gradient at all since I dont have any background color set up, just the Holo theme, that AFAIK has a 100% black background color?

EDIT:

Explanation of the UI: It's 4 `ImageButton`, one gradient blue, one gradient orange, one gray and one black. I was expecting to have the black completely hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Holo theme has that background gradient by default.

This can be fixed by creating a new theme (inheriting from Holo) and changing the window background, i.e.

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
```

Comment: But, `Theme.Holo` has  <item name="colorBackground">@android:color/background_holo_dark</item> which is black...what am I missing here? And why the render doenst show it gradient?

Comment: Yes, but also `<item name="windowBackground">@android:drawable/screen_background_selector_dark</item>`. And that's what you're seeing

Comment: Oh I missed this tag because it's under Theme and not under Theme.Holo....thanks!